# How to show/hide a div while hovering over a specific figure item?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show or hide a div while I hover over a specific figure item. To be specific: what I try to achieve is the following:

1. When I hover on button #1, then I want to show the div with the text for button 1;
2. When I hover on button #2, then I want to show the div with the text for button 2;
3. and so on...

[image]

First of all, I tried to reproduce a simple example (this example is working):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.hide {
  display: none;
}
    
.myDIV:hover + .hide {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="myDIV">Hover over me.</div>
<div class="hide">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However, I am not able to make this work on my end. Does anyone have an idea how I can apply this example to the HTML structure below? FYI: the classes in this script are used as dummies to describe what I try to achieve.

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <section>
      <figure>
        <i class="hover pin 1">1</i>
        <i class="hover pin 2">2</i>
        <i class="hover pin 3">3</i>
        <i class="hover pin 4">4</i>
      </figure>
    </section>
  </div>   
  <div class="hide when not equal to hover item 1">
    <h3>Text item 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hide when not equal to hover item 2">
    <h3>Text item 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hide when not equal to hover item 3">
    <h3>Text item 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hide when not equal to hover item 4">
    <h3>Text item 4</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Kind regards,

Joris

Comment: You won't be able to do this - with your current HTML - without JavaScript. Can the HTML change? Can you use JS?

Comment: After some help: JS is the best way to do it. When you can not use JS, then you can use the solution of @disinfor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I imagine you could use purely `CSS` for the purpose of this, it's much easier to put `JS` into practice to reach the desired result.

The below snippet highlights the use of an in-line JavaScript solution utilizing [onmouseover](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) and [onmouseout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .PinDiv{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <section>
                <figure>
                    <i class="HoverPin" onmouseover="document.getElementById('PinDiv1').style.display='block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('PinDiv1').style.display='none';">1</i>
                    <i class="HoverPin" onmouseover="document.getElementById('PinDiv2').style.display='block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('PinDiv2').style.display='none';">2</i>
                    <i class="HoverPin" onmouseover="document.getElementById('PinDiv3').style.display='block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('PinDiv3').style.display='none';">3</i>
                    <i class="HoverPin" onmouseover="document.getElementById('PinDiv4').style.display='block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('PinDiv4').style.display='none';">4</i>
                </figure>
            </section>
        </div>            
        <div id="PinDiv1" class="PinDiv">
            <h3>Text item 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="PinDiv2" class="PinDiv">
            <h3>Text item 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="PinDiv3" class="PinDiv">
            <h3>Text item 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="PinDiv4" class="PinDiv">
            <h3>Text item 4</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using `JQuery` we can clean this up somewhat:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .PinDiv{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <section>
                <figure>
                    <i class="HoverPin" onmouseover="$('#PinDiv1').css('display','block');" onmouseout="$('#PinDiv1').css('display','none');">1</i>
                    <i class="HoverPin" onmouseover="$('#PinDiv2').css('display','block');" onmouseout="$('#PinDiv2').css('display','none');">2</i>
                    <i class="HoverPin" onmouseover="$('#PinDiv3').css('display','block');" onmouseout="$('#PinDiv3').css('display','none');">3</i>
                    <i class="HoverPin" onmouseover="$('#PinDiv4').css('display','block');" onmouseout="$('#PinDiv4').css('display','none');">4</i>
                </figure>
            </section>
        </div>            
        <div id="PinDiv1" class="PinDiv">
            <h3>Text item 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="PinDiv2" class="PinDiv">
            <h3>Text item 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="PinDiv3" class="PinDiv">
            <h3>Text item 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="PinDiv4" class="PinDiv">
            <h3>Text item 4</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you wanted them to stay open, you could do something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .PinDiv{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <section>
                <figure>
                    <i class="HoverPin" onmouseover="$('#PinDiv1').css('display','block');" onmouseout="$('.PinDiv:not(#PinDiv1)').css('display','none');">1</i>
                    <i class="HoverPin" onmouseover="$('#PinDiv2').css('display','block');" onmouseout="$('.PinDiv:not(#PinDiv2)').css('display','none');">2</i>
                    <i class="HoverPin" onmouseover="$('#PinDiv3').css('display','block');" onmouseout="$('.PinDiv:not(#PinDiv3)').css('display','none');">3</i>
                    <i class="HoverPin" onmouseover="$('#PinDiv4').css('display','block');" onmouseout="$('.PinDiv:not(#PinDiv4)').css('display','none');">4</i>
                </figure>
            </section>
        </div>            
        <div id="PinDiv1" class="PinDiv">
            <h3>Text item 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="PinDiv2" class="PinDiv">
            <h3>Text item 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="PinDiv3" class="PinDiv">
            <h3>Text item 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="PinDiv4" class="PinDiv">
            <h3>Text item 4</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the first pin as the by default selected one?

Comment: Sure. Underneath the PinDiv class in the head tags you could add a style to display it as a block. `#PinDiv1{display:block;}`

Comment: Thanks... And is it also possible to show a div with text when no pin is hovered at all? To be specific: I want to tell the user to hover over a pin when the user is actually not hovering a pin.

Comment: Yep. Add another PinDiv item and then hide it when the user mouseover's a real div. but in the same way you showed PinDiv1 by default, you can do it to that element

Comment: Without creating another pin item, I want to show a default div while the user is not hovering any pin. What I am trying to achieve is to show a div with text to stimulate the user to hover a pin. Is this possible?

Comment: My first thought for this was a standard div, with a style utilizing the [not selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) and the [hover selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) but it would take a lot of experimenting to get it how you want it. You could take a shot at doing it and if you can't get the style it's probably worth a question on it's own at that point

Answer (score 1):

You can try this quick css trick to achive what you need :)

CSS:

```
.hoverable:not(:hover) + .show-on-hover {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <i class="hover pin 1">1
    <div class="hide">
      <h3>Text item 1</h3>
    </div>
  </i>
  <i class="hover pin 2">2
    <div class="hide">
      <h3>Text item 2</h3>
    </div>
  </i>
  <i class="hover pin 3">3
    <div class="hide">
      <h3>Text item 3</h3>
    </div>
  </i>
  <i class="hover pin 4">4
    <div class="hide">
      <h3>Text item 4</h3>
    </div>
  </i>
</div>
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}

i:hover > .hide {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div style="display: flex">
  <i class="hover pin 1">1
    <div class="hide">
      <h3>Text item 1</h3>
    </div>
  </i>
  <i class="hover pin 2">2
    <div class="hide">
      <h3>Text item 2</h3>
    </div>
  </i>
  <i class="hover pin 3">3
    <div class="hide">
      <h3>Text item 3</h3>
    </div>
  </i>
  <i class="hover pin 4">4
    <div class="hide">
      <h3>Text item 4</h3>
    </div>
  </i>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The OP asked if you can do this with the given HTML structure (in the second example). This example is just a duplicate of what OP said works.

Comment: @Yoorizz I changed the html cause I wasn't able to make it work your way.
In this mode the code works :)

Comment: @Synapsis it is still not 1:1 compared to my HTML structure, but this will also work when I change it.

Comment: @Yoorizz yup I know sorry :p

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use JS (the other answer posted will work), you can use the `:target` selector. The caveat is the user will need to click on the element.

```css
div.text {
  display: none;
}

div:target {
  display: block;
}

.pin {
margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <section>
      <figure>
        <a href="#text1" class="pin">1</i>
        <a href="#text2" class="pin">2</i>
        <a href="#text3" class="pin">3</i>
        <a href="#text4" class="pin">4</i>
      </figure>
    </section>
  </div>   
  <div class="text" id="text1">
    <h3>Text item 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="text" id="text2">
    <h3>Text item 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="text" id="text3">
    <h3>Text item 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="text" id="text4">
    <h3>Text item 4</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```